# Django form adding element before a field?

Tags: html, css, django, django-forms

Here is what my current form looks like

```
class sForm(forms.ModelForm):

    """Form to create new instance. """
    class Meta:
        model = sModel
        fields = ('title','twitter_username')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(sForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['title'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Title'

        self.fields['twitter_username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = '@twitter'
```

The form works absolutely fine. Now before the `twitter` element i want to add "@" symbol. Similar to [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzxzBx). I am unsure how to do that ? thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the element you want to add the @ before, do the following:

```
.element-to-prefix:before {
  content: '@';
}
```

This is called a pseudo element.